# Nami wallet and CIP-0008: signData got changed?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, cardano

I have a web application which is using **window.cardano.nami** injection since months.
Following CIP-0008, I'm trying to abstract all the source code to support *ccvault* and other Cardano wallets; everything works fine, but it seems the **signData** method has been changed.

I was using *window.cardano.signData* and the result was a plaintext signature like this:
[window.cardano.signData signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmTX8.png)

```
const signedData = await window.cardano.signData(usedAddresses, hexMessage);
```

I switched to *api.signData* (where *api* is the new endpoint returned by window.cardano.nami.enable() and now the signature is an object like this:
[api.signData signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dJsH.png)

```
const signedData = await wallet.signData(usedAddresses, hexMessage);
```

So, the type is different, but that's not enough: the signature itself (if I compare the first signature with the .signature attribute of the second signature object) is different!

Even more weird: **ccvault** works like a charm!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a legacy version of nami and a new one, best is to check for both and return the correct one. Then just keep using it like normal.

```
   let connectNami = async () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (typeof window.cardano.nami !== "undefined") {
      // @ts-ignore
      return await window.cardano.nami.enable();
    } else {
      console.debug(`Using legacy nami wallet integration`);

      // @ts-ignore
      await window.cardano.enable();

      // @ts-ignore
      return window.cardano;
    }
  };
const cardano= await connectNami();
const token = await cardano.signData(address, messageToSign);
```

Comment: But if I use window.cardano methods, I got the Nami warning about deprecated implementation.
Moreover, I got this problem from the same browser and same wallet extension..

So I'm getting API instance with

`localWallet = await window.cardano.nami.enable();`

and next using it with

`signedData = await window.cardano.signData(usedAddresses, hexMessage);`

I need to use window.cardano.signData because localWallet.signData got a different signature and a different object type..